# How to schedule a task that runs php using window task scheduler?

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I've been trying to run a `php` file using window task scheduler. I've tried using the .bat file, but it won't work.
Here's what I've done:

- I've created a task "Download Image"
- I've created a .bat file, and the content is:

  "C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "D:\server\newxml\download.php";
- The php file that I want to run is:

  ```
      ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
      $doc = simplexml_load_file('xml_edit_feeds.xml');

      foreach ($doc->xpath("//item") as $item) {
          $name = $item->productname;
          $realname = preg_replace('/\s/', '',$name);
          $url = $item->thumbnail_url;
          $img = 'D:/server/newxml/imagethumbnail/'.$realname.'.png';
          $filename = 'D:server/newxml/imagethumbnail/'.$realname.'.png';
              file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
      }
  ?>
  ```
- This is the screen shoot of the windows task scheduler:
  [image]

[image: Action tab]

Is there something wrong from what I did? Thank you for your help

Comment: you dont need the bat file, you can put that command line in scheduler

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this before, but I think you should use a browser exe program to open your webpage instead of php.exe.

Comment: This might work as long as a web server is running locally, and the Task Scheduler can open the URL, but this answer doesn't directly address the user's question.

Comment: Welp, I've tried to run using the browser exe program but it display the sourcecode instead. In the program script I write "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe" and in the add arguments I write D:\server\newxml\download.php. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Eureka! I got the answer to this, so, I what I've done is:

- Set the Program/Script to: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
- Set the arguments to: D:\path\to\php.php (In my case D:\server\newxml\download.php)
- Set the start-in to the folder that contains download.php (php file that you want to run). In my case: D:\server\newxml\